# Init. static members while COPY CTOR is private

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor, static-members

I have a class X, and my goal is to have a special var that indicates a "bad object", in order to implement a function that returns `X&`.
For example:

```
//X.h
class X{
private:
  int i;
  X(const X& other){} //private COPY CTOR

public:
  const static X& badObject;

  X(int a) : i(a) {} // the only CTOR

  const X& f(){
   if(true)
    //return some valid X object
   else
      return badObject;
};
```

The only CTOR is not the default CTOR, and the COPY CTOR is private (I don't want to allow coping of this object.) `Operator=` is also private.
Now, when I try to init. badObject in X.cpp I get an error:

```
//X.cpp
#include "X.h"
const X& X::badObject = X(1);
```

because the COPY CTOR is private.

What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why `badObject` is a reference (to what)?

Comment: try "const static X badObject;" in the declaration and "const X X::badObject(1);" in the definition.

Comment: It is a reference because if not, every time i'll do 'return badObject', a CTOR will be called to create a temporary object, to be returned by value from f() and I don't want to do that.

Comment: No, that's not how it works - you just need the function to return a ref, and each time it returns it'll return a ref to that same object.

Comment: But I just did that.. didn't I? f() returns a reference... But I'll give it a try. It seems about right.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so just make the changes I suggested in my first post and you should be good.

Comment: @bomba6 Yes the only thing missing is the `{` other than that it compiles fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declaration to

`const static X badObject;`

and the definition to

`const X X::badObject(1);`

This will create exactly one instance of `badObject`. As your function returns its value by ref, there is no need for a copy constructor or anything more.